# R data.table fread Fill = TRUE

Tags: r

I am trying to read a fairly large text file with `data.table::fread`.  My issue is that it isn't until line 176 that the number of columns increase from 7 to 9.  This is what I tried:

```
file <- data.table::fread(file = file_in, fill = TRUE, sep = " ", verbose = TRUE)
```

Then I receive this warning message:

```
   Warning message:
In data.table::fread(file, fill = TRUE, sep = " ", verbose = TRUE) :
  Stopped early on line 177. Expected 7 fields but found 9. Consider fill=TRUE and comment.char=. First discarded non-empty line: <<HOUREMIS 2012 07 18 01 D27                 0 422 20.27>>
```

My file should have 4151952 rows, but instead has 176.  I did double check that my data.table package is updated [version 1.14.2 presently].

This is what lines 170:180 of my file looks like if I read it in using readLines:

```
file[170:180]
 [1] "   HOUREMIS 2012 07 18 01 C725405   0.0011432265484  "    
 [2] "   HOUREMIS 2012 07 18 01 C725406   0.0011235834602  "    
 [3] "   HOUREMIS 2012 07 18 01 C726402   0.0005382201178  "    
 [4] "   HOUREMIS 2012 07 18 01 C726403    0.000656078647  "    
 [5] "   HOUREMIS 2012 07 18 01 C726404    0.000738579368  "    
 [6] "   HOUREMIS 2012 07 18 01 C726405   0.0008642949454  "    
 [7] "   HOUREMIS 2012 07 18 01 C726406   0.0009507246582  "    
 [8] "   HOUREMIS 2012 07 18 01 D27                 0 422 20.27"
 [9] "   HOUREMIS 2012 07 18 01 D28           0.00474 422 20.27"
[10] "   HOUREMIS 2012 07 18 01 D718403   0.0000001630714  "    
[11] "   HOUREMIS 2012 07 18 01 D718404   0.0000086822269  "
```

Does anyone have a work around using any method?

Thanks!

Comment: Using `fill=TRUE` works for me with the example rows as shown, and just adds two new columns with the extra values. E.g.: `fread(x, fill=TRUE, sep=" ")`

Comment: Thanks for looking at this - did you add 170 dummy rows?  I think how far down before the extra columns occur is the actual issue.  So maybe it would be faster to print a line of headers before I read in the file?

Comment: Yep, I can confirm that is the issue too. If I add a whole bunch of rows with 7 fields above, it has the same problem as you are reporting.

Comment: Looking at the `verbose=TRUE` output, there are definite differences when using the input with the 9 columns on row 8 vs row 178. I can't seem to find any way to manually force `fread` to scan the later rows though, so maybe your idea to add a header might work.